# NGBoost. Custom Distribution Class (Inverse Weibull). Loss Function is -inf

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, distribution

I have created a custom distribution to use within the NGBoost algorithm which is inheriting from the scipy.stats.invweibull.

See example in the User Guide for the Laplace Distribution

```
class LaplaceLogScore(LogScore):

    def score(self, Y):
        return -self.dist.logpdf(Y)

    def d_score(self, Y):
        D = np.zeros((len(Y), 2)) # first col is dS/d, second col is dS/d(log(b))
        D[:, 0] = np.sign(self.loc - Y)/self.scale
        D[:, 1] = 1 - np.abs(self.loc - Y)/self.scale
        return D

class Laplace(RegressionDistn):

    n_params = 2
    scores = [LaplaceLogScore]

    def __init__(self, params):
        # save the parameters
        self._params = params

        # create other objects that will be useful later
        self.loc = params[0]
        self.logscale = params[1]
        self.scale = np.exp(params[1]) # since params[1] is log(scale)
        self.dist = dist(loc=self.loc, scale=self.scale)

    def fit(Y):
        m, s = dist.fit(Y) # use scipy's implementation
        return np.array([m, np.log(s)])

    def sample(self, m):
        return np.array([self.dist.rvs() for i in range(m)])

    def __getattr__(self, name): # gives us access to Laplace.mean() required for RegressionDist.predict()
        if name in dir(self.dist):
            return getattr(self.dist, name)
        return None

    @property
    def params(self):
        return {'loc':self.loc, 'scale':self.scale}
```

https://stanfordmlgroup.github.io/ngboost/5-dev.html

See attached Custom Inverse Weibull Class called `inv_weibull.py`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.stats import invweibull
from ngboost.distns import RegressionDistn
from ngboost.scores import LogScore, CRPScore

class InverseWeibullLogScore(LogScore):
    def score(self, Y):
        return -self.dist.logpdf(Y)

    def d_score(self, Y):
        D = np.zeros((len(Y), 2))
        D[:, 0] = -self.alpha * np.power(self.beta * Y, -self.alpha) * np.log(self.beta * Y)
        D[:, 1] = -self.alpha * np.power(self.beta * Y, -self.alpha - 1) * np.log(self.beta * Y)
        return D


    def metric(self):
        FI = np.zeros((self.alpha.shape[0], 2, 2))
        FI[:, 0, 0] = -self.alpha / (self.beta**2)
        FI[:, 1, 1] = self.alpha * (self.alpha + 1) / (self.beta**2)
        FI[:, 0, 1] = 0  # Cross derivatives are zero
        FI[:, 1, 0] = 0  # Cross derivatives are zero
        return FI


class InverseWeibullCRPScore(CRPScore):
    def score(self, Y):
        Z = (Y - self.loc) / self.scale
        return self.scale * (
            Z * (2 * sp.stats.norm.cdf(Z) - 1)
            + 2 * sp.stats.norm.pdf(Z)
            - 1 / np.sqrt(np.pi)
        )

    def d_score(self, Y):
        Z = (Y - self.loc) / self.scale
        D = np.zeros((len(Y), 2))
        D[:, 0] = -(2 * sp.stats.norm.cdf(Z) - 1) * self.dist.pdf(Y) / self.scale
        D[:, 1] = self.score(Y) + (Y - self.loc) * D[:, 0]
        return D

    def metric(self):
        FI = np.zeros((self.alpha.shape[0], 2, 2))
        FI[:, 0, 0] = -self.alpha / (self.beta * self.beta)
        FI[:, 1, 1] = self.alpha * (self.alpha + 1) / (self.beta * self.beta)
        return FI



class InverseWeibull(RegressionDistn):
    """
    Implements the inverse Weibull distribution for NGBoost.

    The inverse Weibull distribution has two parameters, alpha and beta.
    This distribution has both LogScore and InverseWeibullCRPScore implemented for it.
    """

    n_params = 2
    scores = [InverseWeibullLogScore, InverseWeibullCRPScore]

    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__(params)
        self.alpha = np.exp(params[0])
        self.beta = np.exp(params[1])
        self.dist = invweibull(self.alpha, scale=self.beta)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in dir(self.dist):
            return getattr(self.dist, name)
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def fit(Y):
        alpha, _, beta = invweibull.fit(Y, floc=0)
        return np.array([alpha, np.log(beta)])


    
    def sample(self, m):
        return np.array([self.rvs() for _ in range(m)])


    @property
    def params(self):
        return {"alpha": self.alpha, "beta": self.beta}
```

I have tested this on the Boston Testing set and a few other custom made datasets which I tried to induce an Inverse Weibull distribution (Extreme Value Distribution) however the loss function is continually returning -inf and I am at lost as to why.

see attached code for running

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from ngboost import NGBoost,NGBRegressor
from ngboost.distns import InverseWeibull
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston_dataset = load_boston()
boston = pd.DataFrame(boston_dataset.data, columns=boston_dataset.feature_names)
boston['MEDV'] = boston_dataset.target
X = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[boston['LSTAT'], boston['RM']], columns = ['LSTAT','RM'])
Y = boston['MEDV']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)


ngb = NGBRegressor(Dist=InverseWeibull).fit(X_train,Y_train)
Y_preds = ngb.predict(X_test)
Y_dists = ngb.pred_dist(X_test)

# test Mean Squared Error
test_MSE = mean_squared_error(Y_preds, Y_test)
print("Test MSE", test_MSE)

# test Negative Log Likelihood
test_NLL = -Y_dists.logpdf(Y_test).mean()
print("Test NLL", test_NLL)
```

This will return an output of

```
[iter 0] loss=inf val_loss=0.0000 scale=1.0000 norm=0.0000
== Quitting at iteration / GRAD 0
Test MSE 101.68170913380303
Test NLL inf
```

Any help regarding this would be amazing

please note that in order to use this distn you must adjust the **init**.py within the ngboost/distns/**init**.py to reflect this

```
"""NGBoost distributions"""
from .categorical import Bernoulli, k_categorical  # NOQA
from .cauchy import Cauchy  # NOQA
from .distn import ClassificationDistn, Distn, RegressionDistn  # NOQA
from .exponential import Exponential  # NOQA
from .gamma import Gamma  # NOQA
from .laplace import Laplace  # NOQA
from .lognormal import LogNormal  # NOQA
from .multivariate_normal import MultivariateNormal  # NOQA
from .normal import Normal, NormalFixedVar  # NOQA
from .poisson import Poisson  # NOQA
from .t import T, TFixedDf, TFixedDfFixedVar  # NOQA
from .inv_weibull import InverseWeibull
```

with `.inv_weibull` being the .py file containing the `Class InverseWeibull` above